# Vim Autocomplete Hints for Go

Tags: vim, go

I use https://github.com/nsf/gocode in conjunction with https://github.com/Shougo/neocomplete.vim for my Go autocompletion.

It works really well, except for one little thing. When I type something like
`fmt.pri`
I get autocomplete option like so:

`fmt.Println(a ...interface{}) (n int, err error)`

Since I'm new to Go, this is super helpful, because now I know what arguments the method takes, what are the types, and also what does it return.
Unfortunately, as soon as I write past bracket, the information is gone.
`fmt.Println(`

So on more complex methods that I'm using for first time, I'm stuck, and have to jump to source definition, or run godoc.

It would be much easier to have that information available somewhere, preferably on the bottom of Vim where the command/status line is.

Does anyone know how such a thing could be achieved?

Preview window breaks my Vim so it's not an option.

Comment: I don't know of a Vim plugin that will do what you want (I don't know that it doesn't exist, either), but such a thing is technically possible. [python-mode](https://github.com/klen/python-mode) has a similar feature, which opens a small split window and shows API documentation like that. If you're feeling adventurous, you could look to that as a model and try to implement it.

Comment: When I first installed gocode it did exactly what you suggest: it opened a small window with the function's prototype. Unfortunately it also messed up other things, so I had to turn that feature off with "set completeopt-=preview". Maybe try turning that on?

Answer (score 1):

I use [autocomplpop](https://github.com/vim-scripts/AutoComplPop) (well, [my fork of it](https://github.com/eikenb/acp)) and it has a feature where it does a small split window with the completion text in it that sticks around. It does this when you set...

```
let g:acp_completeoptPreview = 1
```

I'm sure neocomplcache has a similar feature. Glancing through its documentation it discusses a preview window in several places. Search for preview in its docs and see what you can find.

This is ultimately controlled by 'completeopt' containing 'preview' (:h completeopt). The auto-completing packages often set these values as part of their functionality, which is why with autocomplpop you need to use its option to control it instead of just doing 'completeopt+=preview'.